# Price comparison/history webscraping, processing, and then more scraping and processing

Tags: web, scraping

What I'm basically trying to do is create an automated way to compare a CSV/JSON file with keywords to sold listings on eBay.

The overall flow would be something like this:

Scrape data from a website, save as CSV/JSON

Process said data, remove items based on keywords

Use processed data to search eBay sold listings and scrape those

Create an average sold price from that data, and add that to the original data

I imagine I'll have to stitch this together from a couple of different programs. Ideally I'd like to avoid anything that charges a monthly fee.

Comment: Trouble is the scraping part will most likely be very website specific – so it would be helpful to know what website(s) you have in mind here.

Comment: OfferUp, Craigslist, Facebook Marketplace, etc... The initial data collection isn't too bad, I've used Octoparse for some light scraping before. Although I'm sure there's probably something else that would be better for this. I suppose it would be nice to be able to only scrape new items and maybe create a catalog of reference prices for common items instead of having to calculate them each time.